# scrollable TextFieldWidget number only cropped

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make TextFieldWidget scrollable single-line text as the number inputted( only number that is allowed as an input), but when the number is inputted it exceed the text box size it gets cropped.

[image]

is there any solution for this?

-----UPDATE-----

the answer is I need to add

```
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero
```

Thank you all

Comment: what type of scroll you are looking for, vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh horizontal

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may just need to adjust `padding` in case. here is an example

```
 Container(
            ///color is for getting the concept
            color: Colors.cyanAccent,
            width: 100,
            child: TextFormField(
              maxLines: 1,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: also as @Nik said, you can use `isDense` here

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
TextFormField(
   minLines: 6,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   maxLines: null,
   // change textInputAction want your needs
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
),
```

You use **TextField** also insted Of **TextFormField**

Output Screen Like [image]

Comment: but the keyboardtype must be TextInputType.number

Comment: try textInputType.number

Comment: yeah, but I got cropped when inputted more than 5. while i should change the width of the box. and should be a single-line

Answer (score 0):

Use `isDense` property inside `decoration` and set it to true

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            ..
          ),
```